# D3 V4 Zoom centering

Tags: d3.js, zooming, center

Is there an obvious d3 V4 equivalent to the V3 
d3.behavior.zoom()

.center([width / 2, height / 2]) syntax.

(I've searched around, and most working examples of manual zooming etc run in V3... and the API docs don't mention it as best I can tell.
)

I am trying to add manual zoomin/out buttons, using the example:

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7ec977c95910dd026812 as a base, but with V4.

My page works well, but at the moment I'm finding the manual button behaviour for Firefox is to zoom from 0,0, the other browsers seem to centrally zoom.. hence looking at the .center syntax.

Comment: For anyone else looking at this, I've found an answer, set  transform-origin: 50% 50% 0

Comment: Where you set  transform-origin: 50% 50%? In zoom?